# Grails domain object not refreshing in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class

I have a domain User, that hasMany queues. Adding and displaying queues works ok, but when i delete a queue from a user, the queue is deleted, but is still displayed in the browser. The view is refreshed only when i logout and login again.

Where i remove them:

```
def user = session?.user
    def queue = Queue.findById(params.queueId)

    if(queue){
        user.removeFromQueues(queue)
        queue.delete(flush:true)

        flash.message = "deleted queue with id: ${queue.id}"
        redirect(controller:'queue', action:'index')
    }
```

And is displayed in such a way:

```
<g:each in="${session?.user?.queues}">
        <div id="queue">
            ${it.name} id:${it.id}
                <div id='queueButtons'>
                    <g:hiddenField name="queueId" value="${it.id}" /> 
                    <g:link controller='queue' action='delete' params="[queueId: "${it.id}"]">X</g:link>
                </div>
        </div>
    </g:each>
```

Why the user is not refreshed? When i add a queue to user, it is displayed immediately. Is there a way to refresh the user/session?

Comment: because you save user in session. It's very-very-very bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, keeping a user domain instance in the session is not only is it a very bad idea it's the cause of your issue.

Your user instance in the session isn't attached to the hibernate session so it's not being updated.

Redesign/Refactor your code to keep only the bare minimum of information in the session (user id is a good idea) and go from there. You are causing more problems for yourself than you are solving by trying to put too much into the session and things are only going to get worse if you continue down that path.

Comment: Okay, that seems logical. But how do i access user domain from gsp if i have only the user id stored? Should i fetch the user from gsp, or from javascript, or somehow else? What is the best practice here?

Comment: Typically you will do this using a tag library since you can inject a service into the tag library and a service can look up the user and use whatever properties from the domain to render whatever output (e.g. Welcome back ${username}) you want. That's a pretty common pattern.

Comment: I've refactored everything and now it works. I didnt fetch the domain from gsp, i did it in controller with session.userId and passed needed parameters in the session variable.

Comment: Joshua, one person said that if i store user in session, i could reattach it with one line : `user?.attach()`. Would that be preferable to my approach? Currently i store only userId in session.

Comment: No, keeping anything other than the bare minimum in the session is NOT advisable. While you /can/ re-attach a hibernate instance from your HTTP session like that, you really shouldn't. You should NEVER keep more than the bare minimum in the session. You are doing the right thing by keeping only the id.